# Importing data from Model into a View gives me an error I cannot solve

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I have a model:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public int[] Data { get; set; }
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the controller I get the data and labels, and save it on the model which will be sent to the view:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Report()
    {

        ReportingViewModel vm = new ReportingViewModel();
        vm.Data = DataReporting(vm);
        vm.Labels = LabelReporting(vm);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

The arrays are created perfectly, because I have debugged and are just what I want.

Then I pass them to the view into a Chart.js graph through @Model.Data, but I get an error on the console and the graph is not displayed.

```
<div id="container" class="align-items-center" style="width:75%; margin: 0 auto" ;>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="682" height="340"></canvas>
    <script>
        var colorbarra = Array(78).fill('rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)');
        var colorborde = Array(78).fill('rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)');
        var datos = @Model.Data;
        var etiquetas = @Model.Labels ;
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: etiquetas,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Nº de Custodios subidos',
                    data: datos,
                    backgroundColor: colorbarra,
                    borderColor: colorborde,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

This is the error I get on the console:
[Error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFqua.png)

```
Reporting:188 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
```

And line 188 is the line related to @Model.Data

```
var datos = System.Int32[];
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Any inconsistencies in the code, like Report or Reporting is because I changed it a little bit because is work related.

Comment: I guess you expect that Model.Labels contains the data (e.g. [1,233,32])? But @Model.Labels prints the type (System.Int32[]) and that is not valid Javascript...

Comment: b) You are mixing JavaScript and C#. That won't work.

Comment: `System.Int32 []` is not javascript. Start from there, you probably call `ToString` on an array somewhere.

Comment: @VDWWD - the ToString() is implied. It's all `@Model.Data` can do.

Comment: the @Model.Labels, which is an string array gives me the same error, so I dont think the ToString is the solution

Comment: @MiguelCordero the problem is the very fact that you mix Javascript and C#. Why? The view will be rendered on the *server* while Javascript will run on the *client*. What are you trying to do? Render the Data and Labels objects as Javascript objects into the client code? If you want *Javascript* to do anything with the data, wouldn't it be better to use `fetch` and pull the data from a Web API endpoint?

Comment: @MiguelCordero if you really want to inject the data into the client Javascript code, use JSON.NET to convert the objects into Javascript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use view models properties to javascript then you need convert it like,

```
var datos = JSON.stringify(@Model.Data);
var etiquetas = JSON.stringify(@Model.Labels);
```

Or you can use

```
var datos = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model.Data));
var etiquetas = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model.Labels));
```

Comment: Did you test that?  I think you will have to serializae in the Controller.

Comment: @MiguelCordero, answer updated kindly try second one

Comment: May I say I love you? It works, thank you very much!

Comment: glad to hear and welcome, please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 1):

To pass server-side array into client-side array variable, you can use client-side `JSON.parse()` function with `Json.Encode()`:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Data));
var etiquetas = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Labels));
```

Or if you have `Newtonsoft.Json` package, you should try using [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) method:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Data));
var etiquetas = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Labels));
```

If the array is passed directly like `@Model.Data`, `ToString()` will implicitly called which causing fully-qualified name of the array type to be assigned instead of serialized array contents.

Comment: I guess this works too, thank you very much, but without the JSON.parse, works already, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As shiwn in documentation of chart.js [here is link for documentation of chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) you must give dataset and lable in array format.

Try using passing ienumerable for passing model to view which will implict convert into array.
Your class must like this

```
public class ReportViewModel { 
   public innumerable<data> cData { get; set; } 
   public innumerable<label> cdata { get; set; }
}
```

And your class for data and label must be defined in model namespace
Data model:

```
Public class data{
    Public int value{get;set;}
}
```

Label model

```
Public class label{
    Public string name{get;set;}
}
```

And in view you have to import model which must must be passed from controller and you can directly use that and using razor engine you can convert it also into array at runtime using toarray function